# how to get the location latitude and longitude and update from back ground service

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, locationmanager

i am working on sample application.In this application i would like to get updated location latitude and longitude when a user moving with android mobile on a way.I have implemented Location Manager class as follows :

```
 private LocationManager locationManager;
 private LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
        0, 
        0, 
        locationListener);
    }

       private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                    " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }
```

}

How to get updated location latitude and longitude from back ground ?

please any body help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are intending to get the latitude and longitude while your application is not running, you can use a Service which get the latitude and longitude in background and do whatever task you want to. And also don't forget to remove updates when not needed because getting updates is very costly operation in terms of device battery use.

One more thing, you don't need to check the location for null value because onLocationChanged() will be called only when a location is got by the your provider.

Although I am also new to android. This may help you. You must see the android documentation what these Service class methods actually do and when they are called.
This is not completed code. You have implement the locationlistener in this yourself. This is just an example program which shows a normal class:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class BackService extends Service {

private MyTimerTask mTimerTask;
private Timer mTimer;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
} 
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, 500);
    Log.d("onStartCommand","onStartCommand called...");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("BackService","BackService is running...");
        doSomethingWithLocation();
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to 'implement' 'LocationListener' in your service.

Check out http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/simple-android-tracklogging-service.html